# Нужны ли запятая и точка?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, запятые, диалог

"Любишь его?" - "Если бы ты знал(,) как сильно". Мы замолчали и более не решались заговаривать.

Нужна ли точка после закрывающих кавычек?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Любишь его?" – "Если бы ты знал, как сильно". Мы замолчали и более не решались заговаривать.

Это оформление диалога в подбор,  в конце последней реплики ставится точка. Далее следует авторский текст.

Розенталь: «Так ты женат? Не знал я ране! Давно ли?» — «Около двух лет».

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160#pp160

Запятая ставится в СПП.

Answer (score 3):

Точка после первой реплики  не нужна, здесь вопросительный знак является знаком конца предложения.

Запятая нужна, она разделяет простые предложения в сложноподчинённом, просто второе, придаточное, неполное с пропуском сказуемого:"Если бы ты знал, как сильно (я его люблю)"

Comment: Я имел ввиду точку перед словом мы.